# TelegramBots Update красным, нет meta

Tags: java, telegram-bot, telegrambots

Ситуация такова, что я поставил библиотеку TelegramBots и она подвязалась и все с ней хорошо, но есть одно, но...

Вот мой код

```
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.[[[meta]]].TelegramBotsApi;

public class MyAmazingBot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
    @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived([[[Update]]] update) {
        // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        // TODO
        return "Parser";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        // TODO
        return null;
    }
}
```

То что помечено "[[[  ]]]" у меня выделяется красным в среде разработки. Я понять не могу, что он у меня просит и хочет

Comment: `[[[Update]]]` -- не найден тип `Update` -- нужен импорт, `org.telegram.telegrambots.[[[meta]]].TelegramBotsApi` -- не найден пакет в библиотеке [`telegrambots`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.telegram/telegrambots/latest/index.html), так как есть ещё библиотека [`telegrambots-meta`](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.telegram/telegrambots-meta/latest/index.html).  Покажите, как именно вы "ставили" библиотеку.